# Taking the first date from a recursive event by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, partitioning

I have the following table

```
ID  Date    Event
1   1990-01-01  1
1   1990-01-02  0
1   1990-01-03  1
2   1990-02-01  0
2   1990-02-02  1
2   1990-02-03  1
```

and I would like to create a new column where it indicates the date where event column was 1 such as:

```
ID  Date    Event   Fist Event date
1   1990-01-01  1   1990-01-01
1   1990-01-02  0   1990-01-01
1   1990-01-03  1   1990-01-01
2   1990-02-01  0   1990-02-02
2   1990-02-02  1   1990-02-02
2   1990-02-03  1   1990-02-02
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I am using Microsoft (t-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using `MIN` here as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Date,
    Event,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 1 THEN Date END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS First_Event_Date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ID,
    Date;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

I would use `outer apply` :

```
select t.*, t1.Date as Fist_Event_date
from table t outer apply
     ( select top (1) t1.*
       from table t1 
       where t1.id = t.id and t1.event = 1
       order by t1.date 
     ) t1;
```